# How to drill through soffit corner?

Tags: wiring, attic, roofing

I need to run some network cabling for a camera but I’m very close to a corner and I don’t want to do more damage than good. It’s very tight so I can’t get there in the attic, but if I could drill up through, I have fish tape and rods to get it where I need it.

I’m trying to drill up into the corner (or close to it) of the soffit into the attic. This “valley” at the front is extremely tight and shallow, so I can’t get anywhere near it in the attic. If this was going through any other straight run of the soffit I could do it in a flash, but the cam needs to go in the corner I indicated by arrow. My biggest obstacle is that I don’t know what I’m going through to get there. I generally know that there are valley and jack rafters, but I don’t want to drill blindly and do damage. Looking for beat practice to drill there.

[image: front view]

[image: closer look]

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are asking if it can be done the answer is yes. To have the best chance of success move  ~1-1/2 inch away from the wall left or right so you don’t hit a rafter or joist and close to the exterior siding. When I do this I drill at an angle , it hits the top plate the way I drill but makes the pull easier and not as sharp of a bend on the cable coming out and following the wall to soffit can look like fat calking after painted if trying to hide the cable.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn’t clear. I’m trying to drill up into the corner (or close to it) of the soffit into the attic. This “valley” at the front is extremely tight and shallow, so I can’t get anywhere near it in the attic. If this was going through any other straight run of the soffit I could do it in a flash, but the cam needs to go in the corner I indicated by arrow. My biggest obstacle is that I don’t know what I’m going through to get there. I generally know that there are valley and jack rafters, but I don’t want to drill blindly and do damage. Looking for beat practice to drill there.

Comment: @WilliamRichardson since this general advice didn't answer your general question, maybe you should provide a closer picture and digitally place an arrow where you're looking to drill to provide us with enough info to be able to more precisely answer your question.

Comment: I think your question is clear and I think this answer tells you where to drill, which way to drill, and how to avoid the most common problems.  I would do the same thing.   Perhaps what's needed is this explicit statement: You are drilling into the attic not into the soffit.  You'll probably be drilling diagonally through a top plate so use a long drill.  If you're unlucky you'll be drilling lengthwise into a rafter but you should be using an angle that veers away from the roofline so doesn't actually follow the rafter.  You don't want to drill blindly? Not much can be done about that.